# All contacts disappeared from my iPad 2

Tags: ios

Sometime overnight, all of my contacts have disappeared from my iPad 2. All contacts are still available on my iPhone 4s and my 4<sup>th</sup>-generation iPod touch. I do use iCloud sync but I can't seem to get the contacts back on my iPad. What do I need to do to get my contacts back?

Comment: What did you try to restore the contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings>iCloud, and turn on contacts and everything else you want to come over from iCloud.  This should bring them all back.